# extracting hash data in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with sabre api ( test licence ) in my rails application, 
  i get a JSON response and when I parse it a get this hash

```
{
    "OriginLocation"=>"DEN",
    "Destinations"=>[
    {
    "Rank"=>1,
    "Destination"=>{
    "DestinationLocation"=>"LAX",
    "AirportName"=>"Los Angeles International Airport",
    "CityName"=>"Los Angeles",
    "CountryCode"=>"US",
    "CountryName"=>"United States",
    "RegionName"=>"North America",
    "Type"=>"Airport"
    }
    },
    {
    "Rank"=>2,
    "Destination"=>{
    "DestinationLocation"=>"LAS",
    "AirportName"=>"McCarran International Airport",
    "CityName"=>"Las Vegas",
    "CountryCode"=>"US",
    "CountryName"=>"United States",
    "RegionName"=>"North America",
    "Type"=>"Airport"
    }
    },
    {
    "Rank"=>3,
    "Destination"=>{
    "DestinationLocation"=>"CHI",
    "CountryCode"=>"US",
    "CountryName"=>"United States",
    "RegionName"=>"North America",
    "MetropolitanAreaName"=>"Chicago",
    "Links"=>[
    {
    "rel"=>"airportsInCity",
    "href"=>"https://api.test.sabre.com/v1/lists/supported/cities/CHI/airports"
    }
    ],
    "Type"=>"City"
    }
    } 
    ...
    }
```

How can i extract the data (ex: destination) information from it?
I tried this code but i get an error ``` " undefined method ``each' for nil:NilClass " ```

```
@hash['Destinations'].each do |key, value|
  puts key
  value.each do |k,v|
    puts k
    puts v
  end
end
```

Comment: Is error on the first each or the second?

Comment: on the second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you've specified `key` and `value`, only `key` is populated (with the entire hash data), and `value` is `nil`. That's why you're getting an error.

Assuming you're on Ruby 2.3 or above, I suggest you use something like this instead:

```
@hash['Destinations'].map { |d| d.dig('Destination', 'CityName') }
#=> ["Los Angeles", "Las Vegas", nil]
```

You can read up more on [`dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) here. It's useful for this kind of deeply nested data, and will protect you from keys that don't exist (and return `nil` instead); as long as you don't mix its usage on arrays and hashes.